# Accessing data after calling an API

Tags: swift, api, asynchronous

first, I'm very (very) new to Swift programming. Challenging but so interesting!

Right now, in a Playground, I'm trying to fetch the data from a JSON that I can access using a URL.

I need to store the data somewhere (in this case I need to store an array of `BixiStationViewModel` so I can later on play with the data I fetch from the URL.

I think the issue is coming from the asynchronous process that is fetching the data and then having my code processing it.

You can see at the end of the code the `print(allBixi.allStations)` statement: it returns an empty array.

```
import Foundation


// JSON structure


struct BixiStationDataModel: Codable {
    let lastUpdated, ttl: Int?
    let data: StationsData?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case lastUpdated = "last_updated"
        case ttl, data
    }
}

struct StationsData: Codable {
    let stations: [StationData]?
}

struct StationData: Codable {
    let stationID: String?
    let numBikesAvailable, numEbikesAvailable, numBikesDisabled, numDocksAvailable: Int?
    let numDocksDisabled, isInstalled, isRenting, isReturning: Int?
    let lastReported: Int?
    let eightdHasAvailableKeys: Bool?
    let eightdActiveStationServices: [EightdActiveStationService]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case stationID = "station_id"
        case numBikesAvailable = "num_bikes_available"
        case numEbikesAvailable = "num_ebikes_available"
        case numBikesDisabled = "num_bikes_disabled"
        case numDocksAvailable = "num_docks_available"
        case numDocksDisabled = "num_docks_disabled"
        case isInstalled = "is_installed"
        case isRenting = "is_renting"
        case isReturning = "is_returning"
        case lastReported = "last_reported"
        case eightdHasAvailableKeys = "eightd_has_available_keys"
        case eightdActiveStationServices = "eightd_active_station_services"
    }
}

struct EightdActiveStationService: Codable {
    let id: String?
}


// Calling the API

class WebserviceBixiStationData {

    func loadBixiStationDataModel(url: URL, completion: @escaping ([StationData]?) -> ()) {

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }

            let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(BixiStationDataModel.self, from: data)

            if let response = response {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(response.data?.stations)
                }
            }

        }.resume()
    }
}

// Data Model

class BixiStationViewModel {

    let id = UUID()
    let station: StationData

    init(station: StationData) {
        self.station = station
    }

    var stationID: String {
        return self.station.stationID ?? ""
    }

    var numBikesAvailable: Int {
        return self.station.numBikesAvailable ?? 0
    }

    var numDocksAvailable: Int {
        return self.station.numDocksAvailable ?? 0
    }

    var isInstalled: Int {
        return self.station.isInstalled ?? 0
    }

    var isReturning: Int {
        return self.station.isReturning ?? 0
    }

}

class BixiStationListModel {

    init() { fetchBixiApiDataModel() }

    var allStations = [BixiStationViewModel]()

    private func fetchBixiApiDataModel() {

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api-core.bixi.com/gbfs/en/station_status.json") else {
                fatalError("URL is not correct")
        }

        WebserviceBixiStationData().loadBixiStationDataModel(url: url) { stations in

            if let stations = stations {
                self.allStations = stations.map(BixiStationViewModel.init)
            }

        }
    }
}


// Checking if the data has been dowloaded

let allBixi = BixiStationListModel()

print(allBixi.allStations)
```

How can I fix the code so I could access the values in the `var allStations = [BixiStationViewModel]()`

Thanks in advance, I've Benn working on it this issue for a while now and this would help me a lot in my app development

Answer (score -1):

In a playground you need continuous execution to work with a url response.

- Add `PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true` to the top of your file (doesn't matter where it's added but I always do the top)
- To get your data to print, add a print statement inside your `loadBixiStationDataModel` callback

  ```
  WebserviceBixiStationData().loadBixiStationDataModel(url: url) { stations in

      if let stations = stations {
          self.allStations = stations.map(BixiStationViewModel.init)
          print(stations)
      }

  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for answering! However I imported PlaygroundSupport and added the line you provided and still the same.

Comment: However the `print` statement shows the actual Array I'm trying to work with. So the fetching is working. So I guess I have the data but I can't really perform anything with it?

Comment: Since you're in a you can perform in code that is being called after the fetch, so where the print statement is, or other methods using callbacks